# Special characters won't display after ServerReport.Render() call

Tags: c#, reporting-services

On the server running SQL Server Reporting Services, I'm able to run a report and get back a document with symbols included within (☎ and ✉). I'm even able to save the resulting page as a PDF - special characters intact.

The problem turns up when I create the PDF in C# code using ServerReport.Render() and all the special characters get turned into little empty squares ( and ).

I tried adding `<HumanReadablePDF>true</HumanReadablePDF>` into `<Extension Name="PDF" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ImageRendering">` in the \Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config file but that hasn't helped either.

**Is there something I'm missing the in the configuration of the SSRS server? Is there another way of accomplishing this, perhaps with a special font or by parsing and replacing text with images?**

Comment: You could have the symbols as embedded images.

Comment: The problem is that I'm detecting "tel" at the beginning of a string and replacing it with the telephone and "e-mail" to replace it with the envelope in the middle of the string. The parsing would become a little convoluted but still possible, right?

Comment: The preceding text would have to be a fixed length since you can't have the image in the textbox.